# android SipDemo cannot receive incoming call

Tags: android, sip

I'm developing a sip client based on the SipDemo app. My app receives incoming calls successfully at first, but after some time my app cannot receive calls. `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't receive anything. What could cause this?

My manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.kasenna.android.kasip">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="KaSip">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:taskAffinity="">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SipSettings" android:label="Настройки"/>
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver"/>
    <service android:name=".MainService" android:exported="false"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Main activity:

```
package com.kasenna.android.kasip;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    IncallFragmentClass.IncallButtonsEventListener,
    IncallCallEndFragmentClass.IncallCallEndButtonsEventListener,
    MakeCallFragmentClass.MakeCallButtonsEventListener,
    DialpadFragmentClass.DialpadButtonsEventListener
    {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mswitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.regswitch);
    mswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked){
            if(isChecked){

                SharedPreferences  prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                String username=prefs.getString("namePref","");
                String password=prefs.getString("passPref","");

                if(username.length()==0||password.length()==0){
                    showDialog(UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG);
                }else {
                    accRegistered = true;
                    //registrationWorker("start");
                    initializeLocalProfile();
                }
            }else{

                SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                String username=prefs.getString("namePref","");
                String password=prefs.getString("passPref","");

                if(username.length()==0||password.length()==0){

                }else {
                    accRegistered = false;
                    //registrationWorker("stop");
                    closeLocalProfile();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    AudioManager manager=(AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    Uri notification=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    ring = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),notification);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container_dialpad, (new DialpadFragmentClass())).commit();

    ImageButton delButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonDel);
    delButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView labelView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sipLabelDialpad);
            String currentString = labelView.getText().toString();
            String needText = currentString.equals("") ? "" : currentString.substring(0,currentString.length()-1);
            updateStatus(needText,true);
            if((!currentString.equals(""))&(needText.equals(""))){
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mMakeCallClass).commit();
            }
        }
    });

    initializeManager();

}

public void initializeManager(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.KaSip.INCOMING_CALL");
    callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(callReceiver,filter);
    if(manager == null){
        manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
        Log.v("KaSip_logs","manager created: "+manager.toString());
    }
}

public void initializeLocalProfile(){

    if(manager == null){
        return;
    }

    if(me != null){
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String username = prefs.getString("namePref","");
    String password = prefs.getString("passPref","");

    try{
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username,"cgp.cittel.ru");
        builder.setPassword(password);

        ConnectivityManager connManager=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi=connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if(mWifi.isConnected()){
            builder.setProtocol("TCP");
        }else{
            builder.setProtocol("UDP");
        }

        builder.setSendKeepAlive(true);
        builder.setAutoRegistration(true);
        me=builder.build();

        updateStatus("регистрация...");

        Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this,MainService.class);
        String dataUrl = me.getUriString();
        mServiceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(dataUrl));
        startService(mServiceIntent);

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("android.KaSip.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,i,Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        Log.v("KaSip_logs","SipProfile="+me.getUriString());
        manager.open(me,pi,null);

        Log.v("KaSip_logs","after manager open");

        SipRegistrationListener mListener = new SipRegistrationListener(){
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri){
            }

            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri,long expiryTime){
                updateStatus("зарегистрирован");
            }

            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri,int errorCode,String errorMessage){
                Log.v("KaSip_logs","SipRegistrationListener error="+errorMessage);
            }
        };

        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(),mListener);

        manager.register(me,60,mListener);
        Log.v("KaSip_logs","manager register");

    }catch(ParseException pe){
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SipException se){
        Log.v("KaSip_logs","SipException="+se.getMessage());
    }

}

public void closeLocalProfile(){
    if(manager==null){
        return;
    }
    try{
        if(me!=null){
        manager.close(me.getUriString());
    }
    }catch(Exception ee){
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
    updateStatus("не зарегистрирован");
}

public void updatePreferences(){
    Intent settingsActivity=new Intent(getBaseContext(),
    SipSettings.class);
    startActivity(settingsActivity);
    }

public void onReceiveCallBroadcast(Intent intent){

    SipAudioCall.Listener listener=new SipAudioCall.Listener(){
        @Override
        public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call,SipProfile caller){
            super.onRinging(call,caller);
            remoteCall=call;
            Log.v("KaSip_logs","onReceiveCallBroadcast, onRinging,     caller="+caller.getUriString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call){
            super.onCallEnded(call);
            callTimer("stop");
            updateStatus("", true);
            if(ring.isPlaying()){
                ring.stop();
            }
            if (loadedActionFragment.equals("incall")) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mIncallFragmentClass).commit();
                loadedActionFragment = "";
            }else if (loadedActionFragment.equals("incallcallstart")){
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mIncallCallEndFragmentClass).commit();
                loadedActionFragment = "";
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call){
            super.onCallEstablished(call);
            callTimer("start");
            createUI("incallcallstart");
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(SipAudioCall call, int errorCode, String errorMessage){
            super.onError(call,errorCode,errorMessage);
            callTimer("stop");
            updateStatus("",true);
            if (loadedActionFragment.equals("incall")) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mIncallFragmentClass).commit();
                loadedActionFragment = "";
            }else if (loadedActionFragment.equals("incallcallstart")){
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mIncallCallEndFragmentClass).commit();
                loadedActionFragment = "";
            }
        }
    };

    try{
        incomingCall=manager.takeAudioCall(intent,listener);
    }catch(SipException se){
        Log.v("KaSip_logs","onReceiveCallBroadcast error="+se.getMessage());
        if(incomingCall!=null){
            incomingCall.close();
        }
        if(remoteCall!=null){
            remoteCall.close();
        }
    }

    Window window=this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    ring.play();

    updateStatus(incomingCall);

}

@Override
public void OnClick_buttonStart() {
    updateStatus("",true);
    if (ring.isPlaying()) {
        ring.stop();
    }
    try {
        if (remoteCall != null) {
            remoteCall.answerCall(30);
        }
        incomingCall.answerCall(30);
        incomingCall.startAudio();
        if (incomingCall.isMuted()) {
            incomingCall.toggleMute();
        }
    } catch (SipException se) {
        Log.v("KaSip_logs", "onReceiveCallBroadcast error=" + se.getMessage());
        if (incomingCall != null) {
            incomingCall.close();
        }
        if (remoteCall != null) {
            remoteCall.close();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void OnClick_buttonStop() {
    if (ring.isPlaying()) {
        ring.stop();
    }
    try {
        if (remoteCall != null) {
            remoteCall.endCall();
        }
        if (incomingCall != null) {
            incomingCall.endCall();
            incomingCall.close();
        }
        if (remoteCall != null) {
            remoteCall.close();
        }
    } catch (SipException se) {
        Log.v("KaSip_logs", "onReceiveCallBroadcast error=" + se.getMessage());
    }
    callTimer("stop");
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            this.wait(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    updateStatus("", true);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mIncallFragmentClass).commit();
    loadedActionFragment = "";
}

@Override
public void OnClick_buttonCallEnd() {
    try {
        if (remoteCall != null) {
            remoteCall.endCall();
        }
        if (incomingCall != null) {
            incomingCall.endCall();
            incomingCall.close();
        }
        if (outgoingCall != null) {
            outgoingCall.endCall();
            outgoingCall.close();
        }
        if (remoteCall != null) {
            remoteCall.close();
        }
    } catch (SipException se) {
        Log.v("KaSip_logs", "onReceiveCallBroadcast error=" + se.getMessage());
    }
    callTimer("stop");
    generateRingback("stop");
    updateStatus("", true);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mIncallCallEndFragmentClass).commit();
    loadedActionFragment = "";
}

@Override
public void OnClick_buttonMakeCall(){
    if (accRegistered) {
        createUI("incallcallstart");
        TextView labelView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sipLabelDialpad);
        sipAddress = labelView.getText().toString();
        try {
            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                    super.onCallEstablished(call);
                    generateRingback("stop");
                    call.startAudio();
                    callTimer("start");
                    updateStatus("", true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                    super.onCallEnded(call);
                    callTimer("stop");
                    generateRingback("stop");
                    updateStatus("", true);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mIncallCallEndFragmentClass).commit();
                    loadedActionFragment = "";
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallBusy(SipAudioCall call) {
                    super.onCallBusy(call);
                    generateRingback("stop");
                    updateStatus("номер занят", true);
                    generateBusy("start");
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mIncallCallEndFragmentClass).commit();
                    loadedActionFragment = "";
                }

                @Override
                public void onRingingBack(SipAudioCall call) {
                    super.onRingingBack(call);
                    updateStatus("ждём ответа", true);
                    generateRingback("start");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(SipAudioCall call, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                    super.onError(call, errorCode, errorMessage);
                    callTimer("stop");
                    generateRingback("stop");
                    updateStatus("", true);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mIncallCallEndFragmentClass).commit();
                    loadedActionFragment = "";
                }
            };

            outgoingCall = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress + "@cgp.cittel.ru", listener, 30);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (me != null) {
                try {
                    manager.close(me.getUriString());
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outgoingCall != null) {
                outgoingCall.close();
            }
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Сначала зарегистрируйтесь",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void OnClick_buttonDialPad(final String button_description){

    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            TextView labelView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sipLabelDialpad);
            if ((loadedActionFragment.equals(""))&&(labelView.getText().toString().equals(""))){
                mMakeCallClass = new MakeCallFragmentClass();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container_call_buttons, mMakeCallClass).commit();
            }
            updateStatus(labelView.getText()+button_description,true);
        }
    });
    try {
        if (incomingCall != null) {
            if (button_description.equals("0")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(0);
            } else if (button_description.equals("1")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(1);
            } else if (button_description.equals("2")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(2);
            } else if (button_description.equals("3")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(3);
            } else if (button_description.equals("4")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(4);
            } else if (button_description.equals("5")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(5);
            } else if (button_description.equals("6")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(6);
            } else if (button_description.equals("7")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(7);
            } else if (button_description.equals("8")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(8);
            } else if (button_description.equals("9")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(9);
            } else if (button_description.equals("*")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(10);
            } else if (button_description.equals("#")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(11);
            } else if (button_description.equals("A")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(12);
            } else if (button_description.equals("B")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(13);
            } else if (button_description.equals("C")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(14);
            } else if (button_description.equals("D")) {
                incomingCall.sendDtmf(15);
            }
        }
        if (outgoingCall != null) {
            if (button_description.equals("0")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(0);
            } else if (button_description.equals("1")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(1);
            } else if (button_description.equals("2")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(2);
            } else if (button_description.equals("3")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(3);
            } else if (button_description.equals("4")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(4);
            } else if (button_description.equals("5")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(5);
            } else if (button_description.equals("6")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(6);
            } else if (button_description.equals("7")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(7);
            } else if (button_description.equals("8")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(8);
            } else if (button_description.equals("9")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(9);
            } else if (button_description.equals("*")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(10);
            } else if (button_description.equals("#")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(11);
            } else if (button_description.equals("A")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(12);
            } else if (button_description.equals("B")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(13);
            } else if (button_description.equals("C")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(14);
            } else if (button_description.equals("D")) {
                outgoingCall.sendDtmf(15);
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

        private class generateRingbackTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            Context mContext;

            public generateRingbackTask(Context context) {
                super();
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                int counter = 0;
                ToneGenerator mRingback = new ToneGenerator(0,ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (!this.isCancelled()) {
                        mRingback.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_SUP_DIAL,1000);
                        try {
                            this.wait(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                            ie.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mRingback.stopTone();
                        try {
                            this.wait(1500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                            ie.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        counter = counter + 2;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        public void generateRingback(String action){
            if(action.equals("start")){
                synchronized(this){
                    mringbackTask = new generateRingbackTask(this);
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        mringbackTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    }
                    else {
                        mringbackTask.execute();
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (mringbackTask !=null){
                    mringbackTask.cancel(true);
                }
            }
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        public void generateBusy(String action){
            if(action.equals("start")){
                synchronized(this){
                    mbusyTask = new generateBusyTask(this);
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        mbusyTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    }
                    else {
                        mbusyTask.execute();
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (mbusyTask !=null){
                    mbusyTask.cancel(true);
                }
            }
        }

        private class generateBusyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            Context mContext;

            public generateBusyTask(Context context) {
                super();
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void voids) {
                updateStatus("", true);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                int counter;
                ToneGenerator mBusy = new ToneGenerator(0,ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);
                synchronized (this) {
                    for(counter=0;counter<5;counter++){
                        mBusy.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_SUP_DIAL,300);
                        try {
                            this.wait(300);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                            ie.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mBusy.stopTone();
                        try {
                            this.wait(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                            ie.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

        }
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        public void registrationWorker(String action){
            if(action.equals("start")){
                synchronized(this){
                    mregistrationTask = new registrationWorkerTask(this);
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        mregistrationTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    }
                    else {
                        mregistrationTask.execute();
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (mregistrationTask !=null){
                    mregistrationTask.cancel(true);
                }
            }
        }

        private class registrationWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            Context mContext;

            public registrationWorkerTask(Context context) {
                super();
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                if ((callReceiver == null)&&(manager == null)){
                    initializeManager();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... voids){
                initializeLocalProfile();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        while (!this.isCancelled()) {
                            publishProgress(null);
                            try {
                                this.wait(58000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                                ie.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                Log.v("KaSip_logs", "registrationWorkerTask stopped");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

and `IncomingCallRecever.java`:

```
package com.kasenna.android.kasip;

public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context,
            MainActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
    mainActivity.createUI("incall");
    mainActivity.onReceiveCallBroadcast(intent);

}

}
```

Comment: So, maybe who knows, how to gebug incoming call 'Intent' to my app outside of app???

Comment: I have [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241756/failed-to-create-sipsession-network-unavailable), did you manage to resolve this?